# Thread-safe refresh Property of Object in Collection on background thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, thread-safety

I have an Object, a `Product`, which is stored in a local cache in my app. This product cache is loaded from the database using some ORM code, which I can't easily change. For simplicity, the `Product` is:

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property ID as Integer
    Public Property Name as String
    Public Property Price as Decimal
    Public Property Rank as Integer
End Class
```

Products are stored in a local cache:

```
   Public Class ProductList
       Public Shared Function GetCache as List(Of Product)
           Static _List as List(Of Product)
           If _List is Nothing then
               'Code to load Data and populate List from DB
           End If
           Return _List
       End Function
    End Class
```

This is heavily simplified, but you get the idea.

The `Rank` property is an unbound, calculated field based on all sales in the past 90 days, so that common products appear higher in a search. I want to generate the rank on a background thread - as it can be time consuming, and refresh it from time to time. Something like this:

```
Public Sub UpdateRank
    Dim dt as Datatable
    dt = GetDataTable("exec usp_GetProductRank") 'Returns [ID, Rank]
    For each row in dt.rows
        _prod = getCache.getbyID(row.item(0))
        If _prod isnot Nothing then
            _prod.rank = row.item(1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The cache may be used while the rank is being updated, resulting in dirty reads, but I am happy to live with that. What I do want to do is to perform this in a thread safe manner. That is, update the collection without worrying about if things are added and removed, etc.

Can I use a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` to perform this update? I use lots of threading in the main UI for things like this, but this is a non-UI class in a DLL. I was thinking of pulling the cache into a `Dictionary(of Integer, Product)` first?

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you using shared write access to objects you will need to use locks or semaphores to avoid collisions. When doing this it will tell other threads to wait until the object is unlocked. This takes no cpu-resources. When the object is unlocked the next thread can access it on a first-come-first-served basis (in theory).

F.ex:

VB.Net:

```
Class ThreadSafe

    Private Shared _locker As Object = New Object

    Private Shared Sub Go()
        SyncLock _locker
            If (_val2 <> 0) Then
                Console.WriteLine((_val1 / _val2))
            End If
            _val2 = 0
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
End Class
```

C#:

```
class ThreadSafe
{
  static readonly object _locker = new object();
  static int _val1, _val2;

  static void Go()
  {
    lock (_locker)
    {
      if (_val2 != 0) Console.WriteLine (_val1 / _val2);
      _val2 = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Example comes from a free e-book which is an excellent reference on multi-threading:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking

Comment: Brilliant, this works great and introduced me to this book, also. Thanks. Is backgroundWorker ok to use for this?

Comment: You're welcome .-) BackgroundWorker is fine. The only difference between a BGworker and a foregroundworker is that the main thread will not wait for it when exiting (you can call Join() on the BGworker to solve this though, or use signaling).

Comment: If you meant the wrapper `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` it's fine too (background-worker is also used for referred to thread "types").